# Image Slider using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, image-slider

So I was trying to create a image slider using the below code snippets, for a static website and was running it on VScodes Live Server and the Javascript didn't seem to apply to the page. pls help And I would like to add to add a simple fade and appear transition to the image slide as well, so pls answer this too ^_^

And pls don't answer with the bootstrap solution I looked it up and its not I m looking for :p

```js
let images = ['camp1.png', 'camp2.png', 'camp3.png'];
let slide = document.getElementById('slider');
const slider = setTimeout(function(){
    for( let i=0;i<=images.length;i++){
        slide.src = images[i];
        if (i == images.length){
            i=0;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 2000);
slide.addEventListener('load',slider);
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo+2:wght@100&family=Exo:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Exo:ital,wght@1,900&display=swap');
.about {
  padding: 2rem 0rem;
}
.upper, .lower {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#logo{
  width: 70%;
}
.image {
  background-image: url(scene.gif);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 36rem;
  height: 28rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
.camp {
  position: relative;
  top: 2.6rem;
  left: 7.3rem;
}
#tent {
  width: 30%;
}
#fire {
  width: 15%;
  position: relative;
  top: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}
.info{
    width: 23%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0rem 2rem 2rem 2rem;
    margin-top: 4.5rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35) 0px 5px 15px;
}
.info:hover{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.info h1{
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: black 900;
}
.head1{
  text-decoration: white;
}
.info p{
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.slider{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
}
.slider img{
  width: 36rem;
  height: 28rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css" />
    <title>About Us</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="about">
      <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
      <div class="upper">
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="logo.gif" alt="" id="logo" />
          <div class="image">
            <div class="camp">
              <img src="tent.png" alt="" id="tent" />
              <img src="fire.gif" alt="" id="fire" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <h1>ABOUT<br>YELPCAMP</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
            nostrum excepturi unde eveniet delectus? Porro esse laudantium hic
            ipsam sed inventore, aliquid quidem tempora rem harum quasi quia
            corrupti dignissimos?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
      <div class="lower">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>ABOUT<br>OUR TEAM</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
            nostrum excepturi unde eveniet delectus? Porro esse laudantium hic
            ipsam sed inventore, aliquid quidem tempora rem harum quasi quia
            corrupti dignissimos?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
          <img src="camp1.png" alt="" id="slider"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="about.js"></script>
</html>
```

So I was trying to create a image slider using the below code snippets, for a static website and was running it on VScodes Live Server and the Javascript didn't seem to apply to the page.
pls help
And I would like to add to add a simple fade and appear transition to the image slide as well, so pls answer this too ^_^

And pls don't answer with the bootstrap solution I looked it up and its not I m looking for :p

```js
let images = ['camp1.png', 'camp2.png', 'camp3.png'];
let slide = document.getElementById('slider');
const slider = setTimeout(function(){
    for( let i=0;i<=images.lenght;i++){
        slide.src = images[i];
        if (i == images.lenght){
            i=0;
        }
        console.log(i);
    }
}, 2000);
slide.addEventListener('load',slider());
```

```html
<div class="lower">
        <div class="info">
          <h1>ABOUT<br>OUR TEAM</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
            nostrum excepturi unde eveniet delectus? Porro esse laudantium hic
            ipsam sed inventore, aliquid quidem tempora rem harum quasi quia
            corrupti dignissimos?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider">
          <img src="camp1.png" alt="" id="slider"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- ------------------------------------ -->
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="about.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd better use `setInterval` than `setTimeout` for an automatic slider :)

```js
let images = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/260px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png', 'https://static4.depositphotos.com/1006994/298/v/950/depositphotos_2983099-stock-illustration-grunge-design.jpg', 'http://duduf.com/duf/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Ducati_side_shadow.png'];
let slide = document.getElementById('slider');
const slider = () => {
  let i = 0;
  setInterval(
    function() {
      i = i < images.length - 1 ? ++i : 0;
      slide.src = images[i];
      console.log(i);
    }, 2000);
}
slide.addEventListener('load', slider());
```

```html
<div class="lower">
  <div class="info">
    <h1>ABOUT<br>OUR TEAM</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque
      nostrum excepturi unde eveniet delectus? Porro esse laudantium hic
      ipsam sed inventore, aliquid quidem tempora rem harum quasi quia
      corrupti dignissimos?
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="slidercont">
    <img src="" alt="" id="slider" />
  </div>
</div>
```